# CSS: Add scrollbar only to "content" part of page

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive

I am working on a web app which I want to layout as shown below. Since the layout should be responsive the height of the header or footer are unknown. What I want to achieve is to spread the web page vertically across the page. The footer should be at the very bottom and the content part should be stretched to fit the gap between header and footer, with only this part of the page being "scrollable". I've been googling four hours since this seems like a pretty straightforward thing to do, but I have not yet found a satisfying answer. My code therefore is very limited.

```
<body style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;">
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content" style="overflow: scroll;">Fill this space</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Easy to achive using flexbox. https://www.google.com/search?q=flexbox+fixed+header+footer

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks very promising. I was sure this was possible I just didn't know what it was called.

Comment: You might be interested in something like slimscroll. see link here http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll . it's easy to customize and also can work with flexbox layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flex :)

it's very simple and ease to use. Only downside is support for old browsers.

```
<body style="overflow: hidden; height: 200px; ">
  <div id="appContainer" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; background: yellow; height: 100%;">
      <div id="header" style=" background-color: red;">Header</div>
      <div id="content" style="flex:1; overflow-y: scroll;">Fill this space</div>
      <div id="footer"  style="background-color: red;">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mwd3oqrL/

ps. the body height is just to test it in jsfiddle ;)

Comment: Thank you! Flex is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Flex made easy!!

```css
body,html{
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fafafa;
  height: 100%;
}

.header{
  background-color:#3f51b5;
  padding:1%;
  color:white;
}
.main-content{
  flex:1;
  margin:2%;
  padding:2%;
  background-color:white;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px black;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
.footer{
  background-color:#3f51b5;
  padding:1%;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <p>Header</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <p>content</p>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <p>Hello its scrolling!!!!!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/filineheru/

Answer (score 1):

Is this something like you are after?

```
body style="height: 100%, padding: 0px"
div id="content" style="overflow: auto; height: 80%;"
```

Only tested on Firefox.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Percent values won't work here since my header is a totally different height depending on the device it is viewed on. I think that CSS3 flexbox is the way to go on this one.